# Using xargs to ssh to multiple hosts, receiving :Name or service not known

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, xargs

I am writing a shell script that will ssh to multiple hosts, and perform some operations on them.

my script, test.sh, looks as follows:

```
cat < $1 | xargs -e -d ' ' -I % ssh % grep "example" /opt/example/test.log
```

I run it via the following command

```
./test.sh prod_hosts.txt
```

and the contents of prod_hosts.txt:

```
hostname1 hostname2 hostname3 hostname4
```

I have verified there is no carraige return at the end of this file, yet I am getting the following error:

```
[ryan@hostname1 ~]$ ./test.sh prod_hosts.txt
ssh: hostname4
: Name or service not known
xargs: ssh: exited with status 255; aborting
```

It looks like it successfully ssh's into the 4 hosts but then has a blank entry that it is attempting to ssh with, hence the error.

Any idea what I'm missing here? Seems like I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: DOS line endings in the file?

Comment: in vim I run :set list and all I see is a sole $ at the end of the line :(

Comment: vim recognizes DOS line ending files when they are consistent. What does `:set ff?` say?

Comment: `<prod_hosts.txt xargs  -d' ' -I % echo %` returns 5 lines of text (the last is empty) even on unix-style txt. As a workaround, I am thinking of `< <(tr ' ' '\n' < file.txt) xargs -I % <your-ssh-command>`

Comment: so i changed prod_hosts to be one per line then removed the -d argument in xargs and it works. Now why?

Comment: What you are doing seems to be easier done using GNU Parallel's "--slf hosts --nonall" option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo '1 2' | xargs -d ' ' -I % echo %`  *produces*:

```
1
2
<blank line>
```

whereas `echo -n '1 2' | xargs -d ' ' -I % echo %` *returns:*

```
1
2
```

i.e. `xargs` decides to generate one more output entry if the input string is ended by newline.

Workarounds:

1. Use newline delimited entries in hosts.txt and: `<hosts.txt xargs -I % <ssh-command>`
2. If hosts.txt cannot be changed: `< <(tr ' ' '\n' < hosts.txt) xargs -I % <ssh-command>`

Comment: There's also `xarg`'s `-r, --no-run-if-empty` option: "If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command."